# Mybatis not reporting error on missing typeAlias

Tags: java, mybatis, error-reporting, mapper

I'm using mybatis 3.2.0 with spring 1.2.0 on Jetty 8.1.16

I have modified a mapper, created a new pojo result class, used in the new select method. Everything was a-ok, except for the fact that I forgot to put this:

```
<typeAlias alias="MyNewPojo" type="my.own.package.MyNewPojo" />
```

into `mybatis-config.xml`.

The problem is that mybatis, instead of reporting an error, seemed to idefinitely hang on mappers initialization. One core was used 100% and jvm memory usage increased slowly (up to 1,7gb when I terminated the process).

Common sense says that the behavior I encountered is very, very bad and ugly. My question is: is there a way I can force mybatis to output information about invalid/unresolved mappings?